# vue variable is undefined despite the success assignment of value

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to filter again of already filtered array of objects. I do it through the assignment filtered array to the data variable filteredData, when I check if the assignment successful through console.log() it shows, that it was a success. BUT when I try to filter or even console.log this.filteredData, it shows 'undefined'. I can't understand why? Any Ideas?

````
    name: 'Custom',
    data: function() {
      return {
        order: 'desc',

        hotels: [
          { photo: "/some_address/some_photo.png", name: "Hotel Moscow Name", address: "Moscow, some street, 1",
              amenities: [
                { name: 'wi-fi'}, { name: 'bar'}, { name: 'pool'}, { name: 'transfer'},
                { name: 'bath'}, { name: 'breakfast'}, { name: 'spa'}
              ],
            price: 3000  
           },
           { photo: "/some_address/some_photo.png", name: "Hotel  St.Pitersberg Name", address: "sSt.Pitersberg, some street, 2",
              amenities: [
                { name: 'wi-fi'}, { name: 'bar'}, { name: 'fitness'}, { name: 'transfer'},
                { name: 'bath'}, { name: 'breakfast'}, { name: 'spa'}
              ],
            price: 4000  
           },
           { photo: "/some_address/some_photo.png", name: "Hotel Helsinki Name", address: "Helsinki, some street, 3",
              amenities: [
                { name: 'wi-fi'}, { name: 'bar'}, { name: 'fitness'}, { name: 'pool'},
                { name: 'bath'}, { name: 'breakfast'}, { name: 'spa'}
              ],
            price: 6000  
           },
           { photo: "/some_address/some_photo.png", name: "Hotel Barselona Name", address: "Barselona, some street, 4",
              amenities: [
                { name: 'wi-fi'}, { name: 'bar'}, { name: 'fitness'}, { name: 'pool'}, { name: 'transfer'},
                { name: 'breakfast'}, { name: 'spa'} 
              ],
            price: 7000  
           },
           { photo: "/some_address/some_photo.png", name: "Hotel Berlin Name", address: "Berlin, some street, 5",
              amenities: [
                { name: 'wi-fi'}, { name: 'bar'}, { name: 'fitness'}, { name: 'pool'}, { name: 'transfer'},
                { name: 'bath'}, { name: 'spa'}
              ],
            price: 8000  
           },
           { photo: "/some_address/some_photo.png", name: "Hotel Lisbon Name", address: "Lisbon, some street, 6",
              amenities: [
                { name: 'wi-fi'}, { name: 'bar'}, { name: 'fitness'}, { name: 'pool'}, { name: 'transfer'},
                { name: 'bath'}, { name: 'breakfast'}
              ],
            price: 9000  
           },
           { photo: "/some_address/some_photo.png", name: "Hotel Praga Name", address: "Praga, some street, 6",
              amenities: [

              ],
            price: 1200  
           },{ photo: "/some_address/some_photo.png", name: "Hotel New York Name", address: "New York, some street, 6",
              amenities: [

              ],
            price: 1300  
           },{ photo: "/some_address/some_photo.png", name: "Hotel Toronto Name", address: "Toronto, some street, 6",
              amenities: [

              ],
            price: 1400  
           },
        ],
        amenities: [
          { name: 'wi-fi'},
          { name: 'bar'},
          { name: 'fitness'},
          { name: 'pool'},
          { name: 'transfer'},
          { name: 'bath'},
          { name: 'breakfast'},
          { name: 'spa'}
        ],
        filterValue: null,//initially there is no choosen amenities
        multiFiltersValue: [],
        filteredData: null,
      }
    },
    methods: {
      reverseOrder: function() {
        // console.log("it works!");
        this.order = (this.order === 'desc') ? 'asc' : 'desc';
      },
      changeFilterValue: function(choosenAmenity) {
        if (!this.filterValue && this.multiFiltersValue.length === 0) {
          this.filterValue = choosenAmenity;
          this.multiFiltersValue.push(this.filterValue);
        } else {
          if (this.multiFiltersValue.includes(choosenAmenity)){
            this.multiFiltersValue.splice(this.multiFiltersValue.indexOf(choosenAmenity), 1);
            console.log(this.multiFiltersValue);
          } else {
            this.multiFiltersValue.push(choosenAmenity);
            this.filterValue = null;
            // console.log(this.multiFiltersValue);
            console.log(this.filteredData);
          }
        }
        event.target.classList.toggle('amenityActive');
      }
    },

    computed: {
      orderedKidsList: function(){
        let order = this.order;
        return _.orderBy(this.kids, 'intelligence', [order]); //first argument is an array,
        //second argument is a parameter of sorting
        //third argument is a type of sorting, defined in methods (see below);
      },
      showHasAmenityOnly: function() {
        // console.log(this.multiFiltersValue);
        let runningFilter = this.filterValue ? this.filterValue : this.multiFiltersValue;
        if (!this.filterValue && this.multiFiltersValue.length === 0 && !this.filteredData) {
          return this.hotels;
        } else {
          if (this.filterValue && !this.filteredData) {
            this.filteredData = this.hotels.filter(function(hotel){
             let newAmenities = hotel.amenities.filter(function(amenity){
                return amenity.name === runningFilter;
              })
              return newAmenities.length;
            })
            console.log(this.filteredData);
            return this.filteredData;
          } else if (this.filteredData) {
            console.log("there is a new array of filtered data: ", this.fileredData);
            this.filteredData.filter(function(hotel){
             let newAmenities = hotel.amenities.filter(function(amenity){
                return amenity.name === runningFilter;
              })
              return newAmenities.length;
            })
            return this.filteredData;
          }
        }
      },
      secondFiltration: function(){
        console.log(this.showHasAmenityOnly)
        //похоже, что мультифильтрацию по нескольким критериям можно сделать только используя vuex
      }
    }
  }```
````

Comment: A computed property should not be updating `data` properties, it should just return the value of the computed property. I also notice that you have a line `this.filteredData.filter(...` that is filtering the array but not doing anything with the new array that is returned. Without knowing exactly which log lines log what and when it's difficult to say much more.

Comment: thanks, I'll pay the attention to this points!

Comment: But how to assign new array dynamically, if computed not usable for this?

Comment: With a computed property you don't assign a new array, you return a new array. You then use the computed property wherever you need the new array rather than using the data property.

Comment: If you really need to assign a new array dynamically to a data property then a method would be more appropriate than a computed property.

Comment: okay, but if I filter by using computed property, how I can reuse the computed property itself inside of the computed property??? Could you explain more please? should I use showHasAmenityOnly.filter(blah blah) inside of computed property? If I need to filter getted array another time???